# Copy entire C drive via copy / paste. Will it work?

Tags: windows, backup

If I copy an entire C drive on windows machine to a new drive (via copy paste or even a mirroring tool), is there any reason that copied C: drive cannot be booted to?

This is on the condition the MBR has been set correctly on the secondary drive **EDIT:** and that file locking is not an issue, the copy paste does not have to happen from the inside the to to be copied C drives windows, could be a mounted drive.

I understand that doing a full snapshot is "better" from a backup perspective, but this question is not about "best" practises.

I have been told you cannot get the system back up and running via just mirroring the drive files. I cannot understand why! If it is a 1:1 copy (all files verified to be on the second drive) then you should have everything you need??

The main reason I have been told is about the registry will not be copied.. But surely everything on a machine is a file somewhere?

Comment: Many files are completely locked during normal operation.

Comment: @DanielB all files are verified on the second drive, (Does not have to be done from within windows, could copy paste the first C drive as a mounted drive to a second C drive from a alternative copy of windows, to avoid locking). Although good to point that out!

Comment: No;  Just copying the system files of an operating system is not enough.  If you want duplicate the HDD you should do that.  Read every sector of the HDD and create an image clone the HDD sector by sector.  "I understand that doing a full snapshot is "better". But I have been told you cannot get the system back up and running this way."  You have been told incorrectly.  Sounds like you should find a new person to get technical advice from.

Comment: @Ramhound I have edited the question, was not trying to say snapshots cannot be restored from!

The questions is WHY will doing a 1:1 mirror / copy paste of a drive not work?

Comment: @james - Because you cannot copy and paste the bootsector.  This an actual problem you face?

Comment: @Ramhound, a potential problem I may face according to the advice I am receiving. Surely the boot sector can be restored from elsewhere?  Does it need to come from the original drive?

Comment: I suppose if you cloned the bootsector, then while the system was offline, copied every file on entire system partition, the system would in theory boot.  But if you go to that much trouble just clone the hdd, its less work, and guaranteed to work.

Comment: An example of why you might want to do this: Mirror a drive 1:1 to dropbox.. Then you get revision history of files. Also seems that you could indeed restore the whole machine this way (if you create a new bootsector)?

Comment: I also suspect that you wrote MBR, but it could actually be a GPT - you need to make sure it is MBR before you clone as MBR or the partitions will not be found. Case in this has nothing to do with storage structure. Could this be the cause of your frustration?

Answer (score 5):

This likely won't work.

This answer may be assuming a typical setup, where C: holds the operating system.

Let me start with one example of why you won't get an exact copy:

## Reason #1: Explorer Tries To Be Nice

When you use Microsoft Windows's GUI (Explorer) to copy a picture to a new folder, Windows will try to do a "user friendly" thing for you.  It will look at the picture, and make a thumbnail image, and store it in a file called thumbs.db

So if you copy a bunch of files, and it starts with ApicOne.jpg and then BpicTwo.jpg and then CpicThree.jpg, then it creates 3 thumbnails as it copies those three images.

Then, when it tries to copy the older thumbs.db file (since we are copying all the files), there is a conflict, because a newer thumbs.db file already exists.  The newer thumbs.db file doesn't contain the ZpicTwentySix.jpg file yet (assuming that files get copied alphabetically).  So the GUI stop copying while it asks you about whether you want to overwrite a pre-existing file named thumbs.db

The simple reality is: it's a pain.

Now, in theory, you could just skip that file (and keep the old file), or overwrite the old file, because the new file should contain the same thumbnails (eventually, after the last picture is copied).  However, that newer file would now have a different modification date.  So, there, you don't have an exact copy.  Plus, if the files were previously sorted in a different way (perhaps being added to the directory based on file date, when they were downloaded over time), but then get sorted the way Explorer copies them (alphabetically), then, once again, you're not storing everything in precisely the same way.

## Reason #2: Files May Not Be What They Appear

Some files don't really exist the way they may appear.  C:\Windows\WinSXS\ contains what are called the "side by side assemblies".  Basically, when you install two programs that rely on the a shared file, newer versions of Microsoft Windows will keep both versions of the file, even though they have the same filename.  When you update a file, Microsoft Windows may store both the new file, and the old file.  These sort of techniques have improved compatibility when multiple pieces of software have been installed, and assist with the ability to roll back to a prior state ("system restore") if there are troubles.  But the way this is implemented is complicated.

If you run WinDirStat (downloaded from [WinDirStat page](https://windirstat.info/wds_current_setup.exe), this program will show you the size of files on your hard drive.  The C:\Windows\WinSXS directory will look massive.  Huge.

However, that will be wrong.  See, the WinSXS directory is special.  The directory will report that a file is a certain size.  However, in reality, Windows is using some special tricks with that folder.  What is actually in that folder is a bunch of partial files that share some data.  I think.  Something like that.  The point is: some sort of tricks are used.  And WinDirStat doesn't understand those tricks.  So WinDirStat believes every lie that Windows tells it, and WinDirStat ends up saying that the files in the WinSXS directory take up an absolutely huge amount of disk space.

When you try to run a program, Windows is smart enough to be able to put together the pieces of the DLL file, and make the program see a copy of any needed data, and so the program works just fine.

When you use Explorer's GUI to just try to copy that directory, the "copy" functionality of Explorer's GUI doesn't understand that WinSXS is special.  So, the "copy" functionality will try to copy each individual file as if it is an entire file.  The result will be files copied into a destination directory that is not being handled special.  So the destination doesn't match the special source.

## Reason #3: Boot Process Can Be Complicated

Boot code can do some interesting things.  Different versions of different operating systems can act different, so the specific details I mention here might not precisely match a particular version of Windows that you're using.  Basically, the system startup (BIOS / (U)EFI) will check the section of the disk with boot code (MBR / GPT) which will point to the location of a file.  Understand that the computer is running code which might be very simplistic.  This simplistic code might not even fully understand the intricate details of the file system.  For instance, it might not understand an NTFS Junction.  But that's okay.  Maybe the boot code only understands that a necessary file is located on sector number 6,189,247,145 of the disk.  When the operating system gets installed, the operating system helps to make sure that the boot code knows right where the file is.

If you copy all of the files from your root directory (C:*.*) to a new drive (D:*.*), Windows Explorer's GUI may do things in a very simple way, like copying data alphabetically.  If you're operating system has added a file (e.g., a hidden file called C:\BootLog.txt), that may come before C:\bootmgr (alphabetically).  So the C:\bootmgr isn't showing up in the list of files quite as early as it did when Windows was installed to the C:\ drive.

> This is on the condition the MBR has been set correctly on the secondary drive

Okay, so you understand the MBR may need to find the file.

Now, generally the job of the disk's boot code is to find a file that contains more details about how to boot the system.  For example, with Windows 95, those details were typically stored in a file called \IO.SYS (but there were some other filenames that were also possible to use, instead).  In IBM PC DOS, the same type of functionality was stored in C:\IBMBIO.COM and C:\IBMBIO.SYS.  So there were multiple boot files that could work together.

So the issue can extend past just the MBR.  Even once the operating system starts, there may be multiple "stages" to a boot loader, which may affect multiple files.  I do know of at least one operating system that documents a "first stage boot loader" and a "second based boot loader", not to mention the "kernel" which gets started later.  So the concerns about booting isn't just limited to concerns only about the initial boot sector.

## Reason #4: Data May Be In Use

> The main reason I have been told is about the registry will not be copied.. But surely everything on a machine is a file somewhere?

I wouldn't trust that.  I do believe that once Windows starts up, it may store some of the registry in memory, or in some sort of cache file.  Even if the registry is stored on disk, some of it might be in another file (like a "DataThatStillNeedsToBeWritten" file), and the running copy of Windows may be remembering, "I still have some data that needs to be written".

After the Windows GUI copies the main registry files, then Windows might perform some of the work that it needs to do, like taking the file to move data from the cache file (which I've called a ridiculous name in this sample, "DataThatStillNeedsToBeWritten") into the main registry files.

When, when the Windows GUI gets around to copying the "DataThatStillNeedsToBeWritten" cache file, that file no longer has the details that have now been copied to the Registry.

Now, if your computer loses power, Windows freqeuntly recovers fairly well (maybe through the assistance of running ChkDsk).  However, with you copy of the files made on the D:, some critical data might never have been successfully copied, and so the new "copy" of Windows may not be able to recover as successfully.

This whole concept is why Microsoft made some complex technologies like Windows's "Volume Shadow Copy Service" (often abbreviated as either VSS or VSC; both abbreviations are used to refer to the same thing).  These sorts of concerns are why Backup software may grab a "System State", and popular backup software products may have specialized plug-ins for interacting with SQL databases and E-Mails (since such data is often kept online/usable, and actively being used).

## Commentary

Note that I'm not saying that these are the only issues.  These are just some that quickly spring to my mind.  The Microsoft Windows platform has grown substantially more complex with newer versions.  (XP was notably more complex than 2K/ME, XP Service Pack 2 also introduced notable complexity, as did Vista, maybe 7, certainly 8, and based on this track record, I'm sure 10 did as well.)  So, I probably am missing some reasons, especially as newer versions will continue to add more complexity in the future.

## Solutions

Two tips to help with these issues:

- If Windows booted from another hard drive, then a dormant copy of Windows can often be copied with fewer of these issues being problems.
- Software that supports a "snapshot" often has special code to try to take many of these issues into consideration.

Comment: Beautiful explanation! I wanted to say just this, but you nailed it! Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1):

If you were to do it using a boot disk and then copy without running the os then it should work, just if you want to copy user files and documents. If you are trying to copy past to make an image of the hard drive it will fail with corrupted files and registry system.  If using an imaging program it should work fine. When I work on client computers, I personally use DriveSnapshot found [here](http://www.drivesnapshot.de/en/). I will say the program has an older feel to it but that is one reason I love it, and it works great. There are probably several free imaging programs out there if you look. The main reason the imaging program works well to copy the disk, is because it is a byte for byte copy, so everything is the same. when just using the copy paste command it will mess things up (In my experience, mess things up, means corrupted system files. ). Also the copy paste will not register things correctly in the registry because the registry is not currently running on the second drive to point the system to the correct files.  I hope this will help you with your question.

Comment: I did exactly what you are describing once and it corrupted the entire system when I tried to restore it. (I have learned my lesson from this.)

Answer (score 1):

Copy and pasting will not work.
First many of the values in the MBR/GPT are dynamic, relatively speaking.  Hard drive A is 400gb and hard drive b: 3tb all the sector counts starting and end partition will all be wrong.

The boot record inside the 1st sector of the partition also have values that will be different.  Cylinders,heads, and sectors are now all emulated values, but you might also encounter errors there.

You can copy and paste offline, but you will have to make the MBR/GPT in advance.  Then create partitions, and format them.  Then set the boot flags correctly,  and then copy the files back.  Additional, you might have to use bcdedit to redo the boot menu.

Booting from a Windows PE or similiar disk, it is way easier to use the imagex provided free from microsoft is a way easier more reliable way of doing it.  You will still have to use diskpart to create the partitions if they don't exists.

Answer (score -1):

Various key pieces of information the computer needs to boot up are not stored within the file system on your hard drive, they are stored in specific places (sometimes in a separate partition which you can't see while the system is running).

So no, it is not true that everything on the machine is a file.

In the world before Windows 8 and EFI this was fairly easy; the newer more flexible ways of booting computers have made it much more complicated.

There are plenty of commercial software packages which allow you to do this, though.

Comment: Do you have an example of a key piece that would not be copied?

Comment: The boot sector!